# Whisper openai low processing speed with large files

Tags: python, speech-recognition, openai-api, openai-whisper

I'm developing a web tool to transcribe audio/video to text or subtitles using open ai whisper library in python  .
It's working fine but the problem is it is taking too much time to transcribe larger files due to this waiting timing is getting increased.

Here is basic code snippet i'm using the in the code..

```
import whisper
model=whisper.load_model("base")
result=model.transcribe(filepath)
print(result['text']
```

After doing this an 3 min length audio files takes more than 4-5 min to get transcribed so how can i speed up this process ?

Comment: This sounds slower than what I experienced. Can you also share the specs you are running this on? CPU, GPU, OS, etc

Comment: If your gpu is nvidia installing cuda can improve performance

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same challenge and there are three options I would recommend:

1. Use the openai Whisper API. They've optimised the speed to achieve a real time factor of ~0.1 (meaning 180sec audio will take 18sec to process)
2. Use [WhisperX](https://github.com/m-bain/whisperX) from Visual Geometry Group, University of Oxford, which uses VAD to first segment the audio and then run the segments in batches.
3. Use [fast-whisper](https://github.com/guillaumekln/faster-whisper) which leverages quantization with CTranslate2 (a fast inference engine for Transformer models).

I don't remember the actual RTF numbers for options 2 and 3 but I would say it's around 0.15

Comment: In addition to openAI's whisper API, there are Deepgram models API. Deepgram has its own whisper model (which is faster, has more parameter options AND is cheaper). They recently released "nova" model, an evolution that is better than openAi's whisper large-v2